# What is the property SelectedValueMemberPath of GridViewComboBoxColumn used for?

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

I am not able to find any documentation other than this link, which is not at all useful... http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/api/html/P_Telerik_Windows_Controls_GridViewComboBoxColumn_SelectedValueMemberPath.htm

Comment: It's probably similar to the [DataGridComboBoxColumn.SelectedValuePath Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn.selectedvaluepath(v=vs.110).aspx) in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectedValueMemberPath is the path to the property you want to use as the selected value of the combo box.

Say you have a collection of Person objects bound to the GridViewComboBoxColumn.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

When then user selects a Person from the combo box, you want the selected value to be the Id.

In this case you would set:

```
SelectedValueMemberPath="Id"
```

The GridViewComboBoxColumn will look for the path above in the binding for the currently selected Person.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I did find this which explains more... http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/columns/columntypes/column-types-combobox-column#templating-gridviewcomboboxcolumn